# How should I go about implementing algorithms to be used with black/white and color images?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, opencv

I thought about:

1) Implement everything for the b/w images, then make wrappers for the methods that check if it's a color image. If it is, split the channels, make the operations on each individually and then merge them.

2) Use functors to correctly update the values depending on what I'm dealing with. Problem is that the compiler errors would be really complicated and I'm not used to it, and I think I may end up needing quite a few of them. Not sure if this is a good idea tbh.

There might be a correct design pattern here I'm not seeing too. There could also be a way to do this that's channel/color agnostic in OpenCV though I haven't found it yet, and so far the book I'm reading (OpenCV 2 Computer Vision Application Programming Cookbook) hasn't shown me such a possibility yet.

Comment: I'm not following what you mean here.  Do you want treat each channel independently (for example in a filter)?  If so, then why not just use a for loop?

Comment: One possibility is to treat each channel independently. But then I'd have to modify each method to take that into account. I can't just use a for loop, because a b/w image stores a uchar/float/double, while a color image stores a vector of uchar/float/double so it's a bit different. I could use a if/else to consider each case or use a wrapper with split/merge like i said in 1). If/else option seems bad to me though. Also, right now I'm only accounting for RGB, but I think on certain color spaces the operations aren't quite as straight forward as just split/processing/merge.

Comment: Then maybe you could use a template?  Just give it some parameters for the depth, type and number of channels.

Comment: I don't understand how that would solve the problem. Could you elaborate/post an example?

Comment: It would depend on the algorithm.  Basically, you would make a template like:  template<typename ChannelType, int NumChannels> void my_algorithm(...) { ... }, then use the channeltype/count to implement the correct algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

#### If speed is important, Don't.

It sounds like you're trying to encapsulate or abstract away the type of pixel using OO techniques or the like. This could add an extra level of indirection for every pixel access, killing your performance.

If you're calling staight to a function vs. a pointer to one (e.g., delegate, overriden method, functor) it can still be faster for the CPU, but if you're doing function calls at all reconsider; they're still extra work and if you can nest everything in the outer FOR loop, it will look ugly and functional programming snobs will sneer at you, remember, this isn't a big LOB app that will get hard to maintain. That's why engineers can still perfectly maintain 30 year old quickbasic code, the problem space doesn't need anything smarter (however usually their problems themselves need something a lot smarter than I!)

It's best to implement simple things (e.g., a threshold op or resizing) optimized for each kind of image if you want speed. You can also research **transformation matrix** and see if you can accomplish your work like that. That way you can write 2 transformer algorithms (b&w) only, and, using a similar (or same) matrix do the same thing for both types of pictures.

Hence accomplishing a major goal of abstraction anyway, seamless reuse, separation of concerns. And speed to boot (but hopefully not reboot!) good luck

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the channels could work well with algorithms that work with the channels independently; not all of them do, so this will be quite limiting. You'll also spend a bit of time and space making all those copies.

By functors I presume you mean making templates out of your algorithm functions, with a pixel type as the template parameter. That could work also, but it means defining your basic pixel operations in a way that they could be implemented as functions or operators on a generic pixel type. This is harder than it looks and should be done after you've had some experience in implementing the algorithms.

A third option not mentioned is to promote the b/w images to full color, process them, and convert back to b/w. This optimizes the full color processing at the expense of the b/w.

Answer (score 0):

For most algorithms it is not necessary to worry about monochrome vs. colour images. You either use the grey value of the monochrome image or you calculate the luminance/intensity/whatever of the colour and use that. You choose the measure luminance etc. by looking at which colour space will give you the result you want.

When you have calculated how you are going to modify your images you use some pixel aware processing, e.g. blending two pixels might be `pixel_a*0.5 + pixel_b*0.5`, your pixel class will sort out how to apply that to the different colour channels, i.e. `Pixel::operator+(const Pixel &)`, `Pixel::operator*(float)` and so on.

There are algorithms that are applied individually to each colour channel but they are not as common and often there is some correlation between the spatiotemporal changes in the colours so you wouldn't do something as basic as process each channel totally independently of each other.

Answer (score 0):

My own Image class uses a planar structure (that is, color channels are separate) instead of an interleaved structure. However this is VERY limiting when it comes to image quantization and other joint color processing tasks.

I am planning to rewrite it to use the other approach, to simply be a two dimensional array of pixels. At the moment I am not sure how will I implement it exactly (template pixel class, Pixel base class or a simple three dimensional array).

I also plan to write a planar wrapper for this interleaved image structure to ease any disadvantage I might encounter. One thing is sure, this wrapper will be much efficient than a pixel wrapper would be for planar images.

Frankly I believe splitting planes is rather inefficient, since you calculate various overheads several times. For example, if you want to resize an image, calculation of the various filter coefficients is very expensive, and it would be MUCH better to just calculate them once and apply Pixel::operator * and + instead of the same with the underlying subpixel components.